# $f(t) =1/\sqrt{1+t^3}$, Integral of $f(t)$ from $2$ to $x$, what is the $f^{-1}(0)$?

Tags: calculus

I plugged in $x$ and then solved for $y$ and then plugged in $0$ for this problem but I got it wrong. Can someone enlighten me?
[image]

Comment: Can you express $(f^{-1})’$ in terms of $f’$?

Comment: For the question **you** asked, $f^{-1}(0) = 2$ because $f(2) = 0$.  But the actual question is about $(f^{-1})'(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $f^{-1\prime}(x) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$

In your case:

$f^{-1}(0) = 2$

And 
$f'(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}$

Then, 
$f^{-1\prime}(0) = \frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(0))} = \sqrt{1+2^3}=3$

Comment: Can you explain with more steps? How did you get 2 and 3?

Comment: And yes those are both right btw

Comment: $f(2) = \int\limits_{2}^{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^3}}dt = 0$

By the Fundamental theorem of calculus, if

$f(x) = \int\limits_{a}^{x} g(t) dt$, then $f'(x) = g(x)$